# Any good mobile technology backend reference book

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, mobile, backend

I just started to learn php and MySQL and I have finished the 'introduction' books, but I still do not feeling confident about it. So is there a good intermediate book teaching all the conventions of building a mobile backend? I am about to make an app which needs a more social and interactive backend.

Any suggestions on what I should head for? Where I could find and read some sample code about this topic?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Quite frankly, php is pretty easy just by searching the web. PHP.net has great documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP and MySQL Web Development (4th Edition) by Wellig and Thompson was published in 2008 but is still relevant (since neither PHP or MySQL have changed significantly since then). The book is written for both MySQL 5 and PHP 5.

If you run the same versions, everything you learn there will be relevant - and you can update the versions (of MySQL and/or PHP) and convert your application to use them pretty easily by reading the release or upgrade notes.